# Send notification mail the first time a post is published in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to create a testimonial form and listing page in Wordpress and I'm having problems with sending an email to the testimonial author, notifying him that his post was published.

After the form is validated and processed it automatically creates a pending post with `wp_insert_post()` and the form details are stored in text inputs generated from the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. When I click the publish button it should send a notification email to the author. Here's the function I've wrote:

```
function publish_post_notification($post_id){

  $author = get_field('author_email', $post_id); // get author email from custom fields

  if(isset($author)){
    require_once('testimoniale/mail-config.php'); // PHPMailer config
    $mail->addAddress($author);   // Add a recipient
    $mail->Subject = 'Your testimonial has been published !';

    ob_start();
    include('testimoniale/mail_template/notification-template.php');
    $mail->Body = ob_get_contents();

    $mail->AltBody = 'Your testimonial has been published !'; // Alternative text for non-html mail clients

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
    ob_end_clean();
}  

add_action('publish_post','publish_post_notification',10,1);
```

The problem is when I publish the post for the first time, it doesn't send an email but it does if I, for example, change the post status afterwards to Pending and the publish it again or if I update the post.

I've tried using the `save_post` hook, but it fires when the post is initially created through `wp_insert_post()` as well, and for some reason `transition_post_status`, `pending_to_publish` and `post_updated` didn't work for me either.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use the save post hook and check the post status within the function.You can set post meta to prevent further emails.

Comment: Could you give me an example please? How would I go about checking whether or not the post is being created so the hook doesn't fire then ?

Comment: try it yourself first, you can use `get_post` to pull the post and then use `update_post_meta()` to save custom data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I eventually found out what was wrong and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was wrong with my code: the `get_field()` function from Advanced Custom Fields didn't return the author field value on the first post publish, hence the `if(isset($author))` condition was returning false.

I've changed  `$author = get_field('author_email', $post_id);` to
`$author = get_post_meta($post_id, 'author_email', true);` and now it works

Comment: You mean "author_email" instead of "email_pacient", right?

Comment: You're right, probably forgot to change the name when I copy pasted the code. I tried to translate my variable names before posting. Changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

```html
function notifyauthor($post_id) {
 
$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";
 
$message = "
      Hi ".$author->display_name.",
       
      Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.
       
      View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."
       
      Thanks"
      ;
       
   wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
}

add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor');
```

```html
/* Please try below code for mail send if new post published */

function notifyauthor($post_id) {
$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";
 
$message = "
      Hi ".$author->display_name.",
       
      Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.
       
      View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."
       
      Thanks"
      ;
       
   wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor');
```